# bind_param() error, can you spot the error?

Tags: php

I am receiving the following error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\cpwmytable.php on line 28

I have looked all throughout my code and cannot figure it out. Can you help?

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$eMail = trim($_POST['uemail']);
$currentPass = trim($_POST['currentpw']);
$pwChange = trim($_POST['newpw']);
$pwConfirm = trim($_POST['confirmpw']);

    if (!empty($eMail) && !empty($currentPass) && !empty($pwChange) && !empty($pwConfirm) ) {

        include("mytableconn.php");

        $user = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT id, u_email, p_code FROM theusers WHERE u_email = ?
        ");
        $user->bind_param("s", $eMail);
        $user->execute();
        $user->bind_result($theid, $theEmail, $thePassword);
        $user->fetch();

        if (($theEmail == $eMail) && ($thePassword == $currentPass)) {

            $updates = $conn->prepare("
            UPDATE theusers 
            SET u_email=?,p_code=?
            WHERE id=?
            ");
            $updates->bind_param("ssi", $eMail, $pwChange, $theid);
            $updates->execute();

            echo ("thanks");

            $cookiename = "chococookie";
            $cookievalue = "100";
            $cookieexpire = time() * (60*60*24*7);

            setcookie($cookiename, $cookievalue, $cookieexpire);

        }else {
            echo("No record found");
        }

    }else {
        echo("Please fill out all required fields");
    }

} else {
echo("error");  
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check line 28?

Answer (score 0):

The [prepare](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) method can return false.

Use something like $conn->error_list to examine errors that occurred parsing the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should configure MySQLi to throw exception instead of those silent errors. That can be done using this line:

`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

That way you will be able to avoid these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the statement:

```
$updates = $conn->prepare("
            UPDATE theusers 
            SET u_email=?,p_code=?
            WHERE id=?
            ");
```

The value assigned to `$updates` can either be a boolean or an object, It returns an object on success and false if an error occurred.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Hence, you should check for this like so:

```
if ($updates) {
   $updates->bind_param("ssi", $eMail, $pwChange, $theid);
   // etc. 
}
```

The error could come from something as simple as a spelling mistake of your table or a column name.

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php to check for possible errors but, I think the easiest way is to copy and paste the SQL your trying to run into the console or phpMyAdmin to test it making sure it's valid.